# JPA: merge and persistence context

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have the following code in service class:

```
public void updateEntity(Entity e){
   EntityManager em=entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
   em.getTransaction().begin();
   em.merge(e);
   em.getTransaction().commit();
   em.close();
}

public Entity readEntity(int id){
   EntityManager em=entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
   Entity result=em.find(Entity.class, id);
   em.close();
   return result;
}
```

Please, note, that in both functions entity manager (persistence context as I understand) is closed.

So when I do:

```
Entity entity=service.readEntity(100);
entity.setXxx("lalala");
service.updateEntity(entity);
```

Everything works as necessary and I see in log that generated sql changes only one field.
But when I do:

```
Entity entity=new Entity(100);
entity.setXxx("lalala");
service.updateEntity(entity);
```

The changes are not written to database. Please, explain why. I use EclipseLink.

Comment: Use em.persist when you have a new entity.

Comment: If you ran the code from your first test before your second, then the setXxx("lalala") call will not really change anything.  Check the values in your entity after the find call, and in the entity returned from the em.merge(e);.  For debugging, you might also try an em.find call before the merge call and check the values in the object returned - it shouldn't change anything if the object already exists, as EclipseLink will do the same internally anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following extract from the JPA 2.0 specification should give an explanation:

> The merge operation allows for the propagation of state from detached entities onto persistent entities
>   managed by the entity manager.
>
> The semantics of the merge operation applied to an entity X are as follows:
>
> • If X is a detached entity, the state of X is copied onto a pre-existing managed entity instance X' of the same identity or a new managed copy X' of X is created.
>
> • If X is a new entity instance, a new managed entity instance X' is created and the state of X is copied into the new managed entity instance X'.
>
> • If X is a removed entity instance, an IllegalArgumentException will be thrown by the merge operation (or the transaction commit will fail).
>
> • If X is a managed entity, it is ignored by the merge operation, however, the merge operation is cascaded to entities referenced by relationships from X if these relationships have been annotated with the cascade element value cascade=MERGE or cascade=ALL annotation.
>
> • For all entities Y referenced by relationships from X having the cascade element value cascade=MERGE or cascade=ALL, Y is merged recursively as Y'. For all such Y referenced by X, X' is set to reference Y'. (Note that if X is managed then X is the same object as
>   X'.)
>
> • If X is an entity merged to X', with a reference to another entity Y, where cascade=MERGE or cascade=ALL is not specified, then navigation of the same association from X' yields a reference to a managed object Y' with the same persistent identity as Y.

According to the specification your `Entity` should be saved to the database. But because your changes are the same (`lalala` and `100`) in both cases ( `find()` then `merge()` and create then `merge()`), probably you haven't noticed the change in the database.
I have tested the following cases and everything works as expected:

- I created a new entity and merged as follows (this creates a new entry in the database with the ID = 101):

  ```
  @Test
  public void createEmployee() {
      Employee emp = new Employee();
      emp.setName("Test");
      emp.setSalary(1000);
      tx.begin();
      em.merge(emp);
      tx.commit();
  }
  ```
- Then I did the following and invoked `merge()`, and this time only the `name` attribute is modified for the entity with the ID=101:

  ```
  @Test
  public void createEmployee() {
      Employee emp = new Employee();
      emp.setName("Test2");
      emp.setSalary(1000);
      emp.setId(101);
      tx.begin();
      em.merge(emp);
      tx.commit();
  }
  ```